# How to query two queries in parallel , not sequential(for-loop) and combine those result dataframes?

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, user-defined-functions

me using spark-sql-2.4.1 version with java8.
In my requirement i have scenario where i have given list of countries.

For each country , business logic to how to get dataframe is different but selected columns are same.

something like below :

```
List queries = Arrays.asList(
"select col_x , col_y, col_z from tableCustmer where country='USA' and some logic ",
"select col_x , col_y, col_z from tableCustmerTransacation where country='IND' and someother logic "
);
```

In our business logic
I can iterate each query and run the next business logic each at time.
But it is taking a lot of time.

Is there anyway I can execute each query parallel on a separate executor ?

it is understood this can be done using fold/reduce and union.
But how to do this in give case using java ?

Comment: You are confusing with Actions running in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for the scala code, but the idea is very simple:

```
val df1 = spark.sql("select .... (query A) ")
val df2 = spark.sql("select .... (query B) ")
val result = df1.union(df2)
```

And that's it basically. Both queries will run in parallel. You can add as many as you want - not just two - and Spark will know it can run all these dependent queries in parallel prior to UNION.

Obviously you need to make sure all the queries return the same schema.

Comment: @BdEngineer Whole new question and be more specific pls.